# when i use kotlin-parcelize in my application，after i build my project ,i get a error : can't find symbol readFromParcel

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, parcelable, aidl

when  i  use  kotlin-parcelize in my application，after i build my  project ,i  get  a  error : can't  find  symbol readFromParcel.
this  is  my  BtDevice kotlin file :

```
import android.os.Parcelable
import kotlinx.parcelize.Parcelize

@Parcelize
data class BtDevice(var address: String = "") : Parcelable
```

this  is BtDevice aidl  file;

```
parcelable  BtDevice;
```

this is  where  it used,in another aidl  interface .

```
 interface  DeviceFoundListener{
    void onDeviceFound(inout BtDevice device);
    void bondSuccess(inout BtDevice device);
}
```

i already  add  this  gradle  config

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.library'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-parcelize'
}
```

what should  i  do ?

i  already  find  this  page :https://developer.android.com/kotlin/parcelize
but  i  can't  get  help .

Answer (score 0):

i  find  after add  this  function manually ,it's  ok

```
@Parcelize
data class BtDevice(var address: String = "",var name:String="") : Parcelable{
    fun readFromParcel(parcel: Parcel) {
        address = parcel.readString()!!
        name = parcel.readString()!!
    }
}
```